# How to invert a bit of a packed array

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis, register-transfer-level

```
logic [4:0] count_zeros;
logic [2:0] id;
integer i;
logic [7:0] [15:0] vld;

always@*
begin
  count_zeros = 5'b0; 
  for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1)
    count_zeros = count_zeros + ~vld[id][i];
end
```

For an input as `d8`, I get `count_zeros` as `1e`. My expected output is 2.  What is wrong in the above snippet?

`~` is a bitwise negation and `!` is logical negation. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog expands the single bit value (`vld[id][i]`) to match the width of the expression it is in, which is 5 bits because of the `count_zeros` signal.  This is done **before** the bitwise invert operator is applied.  Since `vld[0][0]` is `1'b0`, `1'b0` is expanded to `5'b00000`.  Then`~(5'b00000)` results in `5'b11111`.

Create a 1-bit signal, such as `temp`, and directly set it to the inverted bit value.  Then use it in the addition expression.

```
logic temp;

always @* begin
    count_zeros = 5'b0;
    for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1) begin
        temp = ~vld[id][i];
        count_zeros = count_zeros + temp;
    end
end
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.6 *Expression bit lengths*.